# Should an API call be in the Solidity backend or the Javascript frontend?

Tags: ether, dapp-development, javascript, external-api, frontend

I am fairly new to blockchain development.  I want to call a function in my contract when a condition in the API is true.  Should I make this API call in my contract, or in my frontend?

Comment: Can you give more details? Smart contracts do not have direct access to resources outside of the blockchain, you need to use an oracle for such things.

Comment: @Ismael I want to complete a transaction when a certain parameter in the RESTful API i want to access is true.  Is it better to use an orcale or just use normal methods in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your condition occurs within your smart contract, e.g. you've reached a certain number of crowdfunding subscribers, you can track the activities of your smart contracts using **`EVENTS`** and an **external monitor** *(e.g. using a node.js daemon).* When the event is triggered within your contract, it will be detected by the daemon which will in turn trigger the execution of your *pre-programmed* code/script. **[Ethers.io](https://docs.ethers.io/ethers.js/html/api-contract.html#api-contract)** has a great smart contract library which you can use to build your daemon.

If you need to call a **`method`** of your smart contract when an external event occurs *(e.g. a user signs in to your website)* its as simple as using the **[Web3.js](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/index.html)** library's **[contract methods.](http://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#id12)**

---

**Here is a snippet of how to call a method on an Ethereum contract (from a JS-based API server):**

```
const Web3 = require('web3')
const web3 = new Web3('https://mainnet.infura.io')

function myFunction(myParam) {
    var contractAddress = '<ENTER-YOUR-CONTRACT-ADDRESS-HERE>'
    var contractABI = [<ENTER-YOUR-ABI-HERE>]
    var contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress)
    var callData = contract.methods.<CONTRACT-FUNCTION>(myParam).call()
    callData.then(function(result) {
        console.log(result)
    })
}

myFunction(<MY-PARAM>)
```

Comment: See, I want to complete a transaction when a certain parameter in the RESTful API i want to access is true.  Should I be using an oracle to access this data from within my smart contract, or just use normal methods in javascript?

Comment: added an example to my answer. once your api condition becomes true, then you can then call that snippet to execute your contract.

Comment: So, what your saying is, I can just keep track using events and such, and do my API calls in the frontend? Rather than using an oracle.

Comment: Others may disagree, but I find the oracle approach to be overly complicated atm. I've used the approach described above and it works quite excellent. Regardless, I do plan to keep exploring the oracle method of real-world interactions.

Answer (score 0):

Just call a method on contract to check the condition ( this does not cost gas ) if it's true call the API else don't . If you want to countinuously check the value of variable you can use web sockets .